# Installing Nvidia Drivers the Debian way would uninstall dozens of packages

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, aptitude

I just set up a fresh Debian (Jessie/8), set the APT Sources to fetch testing packages (main, contrib, non-free). Now I wanted to install drivers for the installed Nvidia GeForce 9600 and I tried following the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#jessie), which lists "the Debian way" of installing these drivers (340.65).

Although I don't all of what it does, I copied this line:

```
aptitude -r install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') nvidia-kernel-dkms
```

On executing, lots of dependency salad occurs and aptitude suggests a course of action. However, **that would remove 70 packages**, including `gnome`, `libreoffice` and many more that seem either unrelated or pretty important (GNOME is the desktop manager after all, isn't it?). Additionally, 16 dependencies would be left unresolved. Hence I got scared and quit the process.

Is it safe to execute this and follow aptitude's suggestion or is there another (better) way of installing these drivers? Wouldn't it be sufficient to just `apt-get install nvidia-driver`?

**EDIT1**: In case it is relevant, my `/etc/apt/source.list` currenty looks like this:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
```

**EDIT2**: I did an `apt-get dist-upgrade` as recommended. I got logged out while it was running and could not log back in (it read something about "regex" and "sssssss" underneath the password field). Changed to TTY1, where it told me it could not load some rtl driver, then continued with something about bad sectors and corrupted file system. Could only restart system, was able to log in. Executed the aptitude command from above again. After a restart, I could log in, but was then presented with a mouse cursor and background only, no GUI elements. Trying to change to TTY1 actually brought up the GUI elements. However, it turns out that GNOME and almost all other programs were now actually missing. Trying to reinstall GNOME with `apt-get install gnome` crashed half-way through with a full-screen overlay featuring a sad computer screen in the center and some copy plus a button underneath, but the font was all glyphs (rectangles). Restarting or trying to `start-x` will just lead to this screen again (it reminds me of the "broken tab" screen in Google Chrome). Guess I will just reinstall Debian at this point...

Comment: You can't mix releases such as adding testing to a stable system and not end up with a broken system. You should remove testing from your sources or make the jump and upgrade to testing.

Comment: @jordanm I did remove the stable sources from the `sources.list` and replaced them with the testing ones. After that, I ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` and even did a restart to be sure. Isn't that the proper way?

Comment: In most cases you need to `dist-upgrade`, not just `upgrade`.

Comment: @jordanm You are right, I forgot about that. Doing it now, let's see what happens after that. Thanks.

Comment: Well, did the dist-upgrade (which did break something) and tried the aptitude command again. Still looked scary, did it anyway. Turns out it really did deinstall GNOME and most other installed applications. Trying to reinstall GNOME lead to a crash to a black screen with only a mouse cursor. I think I'll start from scratch.

Comment: There's no reason to install `testing` to get Nvidia drivers.  The proprietary Nvidia driver is the same, version 340, in Jessie (`stable`), Stretch (`testing`), and Sid (`unstable`).   The newer 352 driver is available only in `experimental`.  I would install the `bumblebee` package, first with the free "nouveau" drivers, after that's working, go to proprietary if necessary: https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee/

Comment: @RobertL you are right. The reason why I would like to go with `testing` simply in order to have more recent versions of some packages. Meanwhile, I set the system up again and it looks like everythin works although I still have the problem that the GNOME UI is not showing after login unless I hit `CTRL+ALT+F1`. The 340 driver seems to be the correct one for me as I have a GeForce 9600 GT installed.

Comment: Great. A little concerning about the Gnome setup though.  Do you also know about jessie-backports?  That's another way to get recent versions of some packages.  I'm definitely not against rolling with testing, I'm just mentioning the alternatives as there are caveats with testing.  Another alternative method is to stay on stable/backports and if you need specific newer versions not in backports, then `apt-get source` on the package and build it in stable (doesn't always work, but often does.)  Occasionally in testing you hit hiccups which could disrupt your work.